# High Sierra Breaks FileMaker PHP Include

Tags: php, include, filemaker

I am trying to run a function that imports items from a FileMaker database. The function includes a PHP file. The PHP file includes/connects to the FileMaker API and imports database items. The output of the PHP file is then written to an HTML file, which is displayed on my site.

The function works fine on El Capitan and Sierra, but not on High Sierra, which I need to upgrade to. On High Sierra, the command breaks inexplicably whenever the included PHP file tries to include the FileMaker API. Why am I unable to include the FileMaker API on High Sierra, yet able to do so perfectly well on Sierra and El Capitan?

Generally I use FileMaker 14, but the problem persists on FileMaker 16. Running PHP version 5.5.38 and FileMaker 14.0.6.

Comment: Are there any errors messages produced that you can add to your question?

Comment: How did you determine that something "breaks inexplicably"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High Sierra has PHP 7, which is not compatible with the FileMaker API for PHP. You can try this rewritten version of the API which is compatible and see if it helps you.

[FileMaker API for PHP 5.5+ on Github](https://github.com/airmoi/FileMaker/)

If that doesn't help, you need to check the PHP error logs to see what breaks.

Comment: Ended up installing php 5.6 through terminal instead of using the API.